# Faster to call kind_of? or iterate through an array with one value?

Tags: ruby

In short, is the cost (in time and cpu) higher to call kind_of? twice or to create a new array with one value, then iterate through it? The 'backstory' below simply details why I need to know this, but is not a necessary read to answer the question.

**Backstory**:

I have a bunch of location data. Latitude/longitude pairs and the name of the place they represent. I need to sort these lat/lon values by distance from another lat/lon pair provided by a user. I have to calculate the distances on the fly, and they aren't known before.

I was thinking it would be easy to do this by adding the `distance => placename` map to a hash, then get a keyset and sort that, then read out the values in that order. However, there is the potential for two distances being equal, making two keys equal to each other.

I have come up with two solutions to this, either I map

```
if hash.has_key?(distance)
  hash[distance].kind_of? Array
   ? hash[distance] << placename
   : hash.merge!({distance => [hash[distance], placename]})
else
  hash.merge!({distance => placename})
end
```

then when reading the values I check

```
hash[distance] kind_of? Array ? grab the placename : iterate through hash and grab all placenames
```

each time. Or I could make each value an array from the start even if it has only one placename.

Comment: Probably, it is difficult to understand your question. Maybe you can improve it.

Comment: I have edited the question, hopefully it is easier to read now.

Comment: Why don't you do a benchmark comparing the two methods? Also, I'd advise against a multi-line ternary, that's what `if` statements are for.

Comment: I know.. ruby nested if statements just get to me for some unknown reason though... How would one go about benchmarking something like this though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, this sounds like a very negligible performance issue, so I'd say just go with whatever feels better to you.

If you really believe that this has a real world performance impact (and frankly, there are other areas of Ruby you should worry more about speed-wise), reduce your problem to the simplest form that still resembles your problem and use the Benchmark module:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/index.html

Answer (score 3):

You've probably spent more time thinking about the issue than you will ever save in CPU time. Developer brain time (both yours and others who will maintain the code when you're gone) is often much more precious than CPU cycles. **Focus on code clarity**.

If you get indications that your code is a bottleneck, it may be a good idea to benchmark it, but don't forget to benchmark both **before and after** any changes you make, to make sure that you are actually **improving** the code. It is surprisingly how often "optimizations" aren't improving the code at all, just making it harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that you'll achieve both higher performance and better legibility using the built-in `Enumerable#group_by` method.

As others have said, it's likely that this isn't a bottleneck, that gains will be negligible in any case and that you should focus on other things!